# Flutter - Delete Cloud function for Firebase Firestore data when user uninstall the iOS and Android app from the respective devices

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions

I am working on flutter app and using cloud firestore to save all users list after signup. So if any user uninstall the app, i want to write delete cloud function to delete that user details automatically from firestore to avoid push notification or any other updates.

I am using firebase analytics also, so when it fire app_remove event, i need automatically trigger delete cloud function.
Please help me on backend code for this as i am not aware of backend code.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [auth trigger functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events)

For example, you can create `authUserDeleted´ function and handle all such actions there.

```
exports.authUserDeleted = functions
    .runWith(runtimeOpts)
    .region(regionName)
    .auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
  console.log('deleted user: ' + JSON.stringify(user));

      // handle necessary actions for the deleted user

      return true;
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But i am not using firebase authentication. Using my server email password authentication, after that i am storing user details in firestore. Then will your solution work ?

Comment: as I know, google-auth-triggers comes from from firebase auth, therefore this solution won't be usable for custom auth as in your case.

Comment: btw. firebase auth has email+password login as well. If you already is using Firestore, I suggest integrating auth as well, this will allow you leverage google-cloud functions to full extent

Comment: Thank you so much. I am using Firestore already. So i can try to use email+password login of firebase auth.